# django queryset: how to get items after a particular id in the queryset

Tags: python, django

I have a list of posts with id:

I want to sort all the posts based on publish_date and get all the posts after an id.

The following gives me queryset of all posts  ordered in publish_date

```
articles = Article.objects.all().order_by('-publish_date')
```

After this how to get queryset with posts after a given id of post.

The ids are not in order. The posts are sorted based on published_date. So the ids can be 10, 12, 5, 7, 2, 32 etc as per published_date order . So if i want the posts after id 5 it should return queryset with ids order 7, 2, 32 only

Answer (score 2):

To get all articles with `publish_date` greater than a particular date, you can use [`__gt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#gt):

```
article = Articles.objects.get(id=5)
articles = Articles.objects.filter(publish_date__gt=article.publish_date)
```

If you only want the ids, then you can use `values_list()`.

```
ids = articles.values_list('pk', flat=True)
```

Comment: The ids are not in order. The posts are sorted based on published_date. So the ids can be 10, 12, 5, 7, 2, 32 etc as per published_date order . So if i want the posts after id 5 it should return 7, 2, 32 only

Comment: Then use `publish_date__gt` instead of `id__gt`.

Comment: thats obvious.  But i am also looking for getting a sliced results given the id from which i want

Comment: I mean the same as getting 7, 2, 32 from 10, 12, 5, 7, 2, 32 as per my previous comment. I felt its like slicing.

Comment: But my `publish_date__gt=article.publish_date` already gives you those articles with ids 7, 2, 32 that you say you want. If you just want the ids then use `values_list()`.

Comment: It gives the entire set.  i want only those after a particular id from the entire set. Not the entire set

Comment: It's not the entire set. It's only those with publish dates greater than that publish date.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164336/discussion-between-santhosh-yedidi-and-alasdair).